# HTTP 500 Error Ionos with TYPO3 because of Rewrite Non-www to www in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, typo3-9.x, http-status-code-500

I got the following code in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.de [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.de/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

If I call the url without "www" everything works fine! But with "www" it ends with http 500 error!
So on my development Server erverything works fine, with and without www!
On Ionos Server I can do what I want I guess.
I got https://www.expample.de in my Siteconfiguration of TYPO3 9.5 but it doesnt matter. Does anybody know a solution?

I think this is maybe not a .htaccess problem?!

Comment: You redirect non-HTTPS to HTTPS, but you ALSO redirect example.de (with or without HTTPS) to HTTP www.example.de - why are you redirecting to HTTP? This makes no sense.

Comment: General tips: 1. Look in your logs. E.g. ssl_error.log, ssl_access.log 2. besides the 500, do you see an error in your browser, e.g. redirect loop?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with http and https but it doesnt matter.
I guess it s not a problem with htaccess.
Ionos support tried it too with everything I tried before and nothing works.
I dont understand why the website works fine without www but bring an error with www...

Comment: I dont have an access to logs on this server and Ionos told me that they dont have logs for this type of shared servers.
In the Browser I cant see anything!

Comment: The question could get clarified much more and it might be possible to answer. You wrote in the comment "I dont understand why the website works fine without www but bring an error with www". You did not write that in the question. You could update it and write what exactly works and what doesn't. Which exact URLs did you try that failed and what works. Did it work without the .htaccess lines above? Can you load the TYPO3 backend or do you get an error too? Did you look in the backend module SYSTEM / Log (as alternative to logs on the system) which shows you some error messages too.

Comment: Also, again, why do you redirect to http in one rule and https in the next, is `https://www.expample.de`a typo (note the p after x) etc. Did you clear browser cache (browsers store redirects, this might muck things up). Narrowing the problem down you might find the error yourself but in any case, it might make it easier for someone to answer.

Comment: Wihtout the htaccess file I can access the website without www. I changed the question now!
I dont come into the backend with www but without! 
In the typo3 logs I only get one error for the autodisccover mode from Ionos which is used for exchange emails!

I cleared every cache I could clear and tried every browser I have on my maschine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix for IONOS hosted TYPO3 installations where adding www to the URL gives a 500 error:**

1. Go to your install tool, `/typo3/install.php` should be accessible with www in the URL.
2. Go to `Settings` and open `Configure Installation-Wide Options`
3. Under `[SYS][trustedHostsPattern]` where `SERVER_NAME` is set by default, add your domain, for example. `.*\.domain\.com` (There are other examples given in the install tool).
4. Save these changes, the website is now accessible with www.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the fact... It works now !!!